# Alarm manager INTERVAL_DAY not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager, background-service

I want run some piece of code every day arond at 8 a.m.
I have this code in onCreate in MainActivity

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PriceAmountService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pintent);
```

But this run the job every time when app is started.
Is my code good or wrong? Is this code on right place (onCreate)? What I do wrong?

My min API is 14

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Doug Stevenson I solve this problem by adding simple if to my method.
My method for raise some job exactly at 8:00am is:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if (Calendar.getInstance().after(cal)) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PriceAmountService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pintent);
```

Answer (score 4):

This code is telling AlarmManager that the first alarm should be at 8am on the same day as the current day that this code is running.  If you are running this particular code *after* 8am on any given day, that first 8am occurrence would be in the past, and AlarmManager may choose to run it immediately, because it missed the first occurrence and will try to make up for it.  If you want the first alarm to be 8pm the *next* day, you will have to set that in your calendar by adding a day to it.

Comment: Thanks for replay. You have right. But I don't understand. I create and setup alarm in onCreate method of MainActivity. And if I add one day to cal, alarm will never invoke today. Or I'm wrong with this.